# need to count based on the change in state

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on one a situation, that requires me to count the number based on the change in states per method. the dataframe, `content` is:

```
count   method_a method_b
1       A        A  
175     B        A  
179     A        A
242     D        C
243     B        C
```

requirement is that, if there is a change in state from *A* to *B* in `method_a` & `method_b`

I tried the below way:

```py
A, B, C, D = 0, 0, 0, 0 
for i in range(len(content)-1):
    if ((content.method_a.iloc[i]) != (content.method_a.iloc[i+1])):
        if content.method_a.iloc[i] == 'A':
            A_ = content.count.iloc[i+1] - content.count.iloc[i]
            A = A + A_
        elif content.method_a.iloc[i] == 'B':
            B_ = content.count.iloc[i+1] - content.count.iloc[i]
            B = B + B_
        elif content.method_a.iloc[i] == 'C':
            C_ = content.count.iloc[i+1] - content.count.iloc[i]
            C = C + C_
        elif content.method_a.iloc[i] == 'D':
            D_ = content.count.iloc[i+1] - content.count.iloc[i]
            D = D + D_
```

the solution should be like: for `method_a`: `A` = 237, `B` = 4, `C` = 0, `D`= 1
`method_b` : `A` = 241, `B` = 0, `C` = 1, `D`= 0.

**Edit:**

The value of `A` is the difference between the changed state and current state:
eg: `method_a` : `A` changed state after `count`(175-1) 174, then from `count`(242-179) which is 63, so the total `A`'s is `174+63` `=` `237`
same with `method_b` state `A` changed from `A` to `C` after `241` cycles `count` (242-1) 
we need to add the count until the state doesn't change. 242-179 + 179-175 + 175-1.

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you explain the logic how are you calculating the values of `A, B, C, D`

Comment: I ain't able to understand the logic.

Comment: updated the values calculation. please don't downvote, the question is valid i can rephrase the required information. much thanks.

Comment: Seems that for `method_b`, `A` should be 242 - 179 = 63.

Comment: @RootTwo we need to add the count until the state doesn't change. 242-179 + 179-175 + 175-1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a job for `DataFrame.shift` and `DataFrame.groupby`

```
import io
import pandas as pd

data = io.StringIO("""
count, method_a, method_b
   1,      A,        A
 175,      B,        A
 179,      A,        A
 242,      D,        C
 243,      B,        C
    """.strip())

df = pd.read_csv(data, skipinitialspace=True)

# create a column with the change in counts
df['delta'] = df['count'].shift(-1) - df['count']

# then groupby 'method_a' column and sum the `delta` column
df.groupby('method_a')['delta'].sum()
```

returns:

```
method_a
A    237.0
B      4.0
D      1.0
Name: delta, dtype: float64
```

Similarly for `method_b`:

```
df.groupby('method_b')['delta'].sum()
```

returns:

```
method_b
A    241.0
C      1.0
Name: delta, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrongly defined `A, B, C, D =[], [], [], []` where is just need to set the `count` to zero.

`A, B, C, D = 0,0,0,0`.

This count will be updated whenever there is a change in state.